# Why does my program freeze after a return ?

Tags: .net, uwp

I have this class :

```
public class ImgurAPI
{
    private string ClientId = "id";
    private string ClientSecret = "secret";
    private string BasicUri = "https://api.imgur.com/3/";
    private HttpClient HttpClient = new HttpClient();
    public ImgurAPI()
    {
        HttpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "Client-ID " + ClientId);
    }

    private async Task<HttpContent> doRequest(string urlQuery)
    {
        HttpResponseMessage response = await HttpClient.GetAsync(urlQuery);
        return response.Content;
    }
    public HttpContent getImages(string search, int minSizeX, int minSizeY, string imageType, int page)
    {
        var url = BasicUri + "gallery/search/top/" + page.ToString() + "/";
        url += "?q=" + search;
        Task<HttpContent> task = doRequest(url);
        return task.Result;
    }
}
```

That I call this way :

```
private void SearchImageClicked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   HttpContent content = api.getImages(SearchBox.Text, 0, 0, "png", 1);
   // other code here
}
```

But when `getImages` return, my program freeze. I put a breakpoint on             `return task.Result;` and it goes there. But I also put a breakpoint after the `getImages` call and it doesn't go there, my program freeze and I have to kill the process to make it stop.

How it it possible ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is because you're mixing sync and async. This line causes a deadlock:

```
return task.Result;
```

In `doRequest`, you're using `await`, which captures the current synchronisation context (because you didn't specify `ConfigureAwait(false)`. When `HttpClient.GetAsync(urlQuery)` completes, the scheduler tries to run the continuation on the captured context, i.e. on the UI thread. But the UI thread is already busy waiting for `doRequest` to complete, so the continuation in `doRequest` can't be executed: you have a deadlock.

When you use `async/await`, you should use it all the way; you should *not* wait synchronously for an async method to complete. In your case, the easiest fix is to make `getImages` async as well, and change the consuming code to be async.

See [this article](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html) by Stephen Cleary for more details about this issue.

Answer (score 1):

When you call `task.Result` you basically force your calling thread to wait until the other thread will finish.

See [Task.Result](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321468(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Both your `getImages` and `SearchImageClicked` must also be `async`.

```
public async Task<HttpContent> getImages(string search, int minSizeX, int minSizeY, string imageType, int page)
{
    var url = BasicUri + "gallery/search/top/" + page.ToString() + "/";
    url += "?q=" + search;
    return await doRequest(url);
}
```

and

```
private async void SearchImageClicked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   HttpContent content = await api.getImages(SearchBox.Text, 0, 0, "png", 1);
   // other code here
}
```